# Can we use local notifications for setting reminder about any event?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing an App in which there are lot of programs in table view.There is an option of setting reminder for each program when particular program starts.User can set any number of reminders.Can I use local notifications for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Local notifications can serve your purpose.